# Finding the beginning and end of a substring using regex

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string

I have an awful time with regular expressions, so I usually resort to lousy kludges and workarounds when parsing strings. I need to get better at using regex. This one seems simple to me, but I don't even know where to start.

Here's the string output from my device:

```
testString = IP:192.168.5.210\rPlaylist:1\rEnable:On\rMode:HDMI\rLineIn:unbal\r
```

Example:
I want to find if the device is off or on. I need to search for the string "Enable:" then locate the carriage return and determine if the word between Enable: and \r is off or on. It seems like that's what regex is for or do I totally misunderstand it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Additional information - Maybe I need to expand on the question.

Based on the answers, finding whether or not the device is Enabled appears to be fairly simple. Since I get a return string is similar to a key/value pair what's more vexing determining the substring between the : and the carriage return. A number of these pairs have a response with lengths that vary significantly, such as DeviceLocation, DeviceName, IPAddress. In fact, the device responds to every command sent to it by returning the entire status list, 48 key/value pairs, which I then must parse even if I only need to know one property.

Also based on your answers .... regular expressions is not the way to go.

Thanks for any help.
Norm

Comment: Why do you need to add the needless complexity of a regex to this simple problem? Use IndexOf to locate *Enable:*, and then use SubString based on that index position + Length('Enable:') to read two characters, which will be *On* or *Of*.

Comment: If you think that is a way to do it then try it. When posting on SO you should provide concrete code examples and ask on that, not in the air.

Comment: In fact, since you're dealing with a simple string, it's even simpler. If you know it will always contain *Enable:* and either *On* or *Off*, simply use `IndexOf(':On')`. If the result is > 0, it's enabled; if it's 0, it's not. Done. One short line of code.

Comment: @KenWhite  -- Don't get me wrong, I want to stay as far away as possible from regex for this task. Since I know so little about it, I wondered if that would be the direction to go. Based on the comments, I would say that it is not.

Comment: Based on Additional information, you should work instead with the Key/value pair that is inherent in this string. Based on wanted any value possible perform this action `string[] testReturn = testString.Split('\r'); foreach(string a in testReturn){ if(itemSearch == a.Split(':')[0])//use a.Split(':')[1] as value of define`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest for a simple line as shown, ask for one or the other, but verify as well. Based partially off Ken White's suggestions.

```
if(input.Contains(":On")){
    //DoWork()
}else{
    if(input.Contains(":Off"))
        //DoOtherWork
}
```

This presumes that ":On" and ":Off" will not appear anywhere else in the string, even with a different string.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following code:

```
// This regular expression matches text 'Enabled: ' followed by one or more non '\r' followed by '\r'
// RegexOptions.Multiline is optional but MAY be necessary on other platforms.
// Also, '\r' is not a line break. '\n' is.
Regex regex = new Regex("Enable: ([^\r]+)\r", RegexOptions.Multiline);

string input = "IP:192.168.5.210\rPlaylist: 1\rEnable: On\rMode: HDMI\rLineIn: unbal\r";

var matches = regex.Match(input);
Debug.Assert(matches != Match.Empty);

// The match variable will contain 2 Groups:
// First will be 'Enabled: On\r'
// The other is 'On' since we enclosed ([^\r]+) in ().
Console.WriteLine(matches.Groups[1]);
```

Comment: Note that your input has extra spaces, presumably from pasting `IP:192.168.5.210\rPlaylist:1\rEnable:On\rMode:HDMI\rLineIn:unbal\r` into visual studio, *then* adding the quotes. If you start with the quotes and paste into them it won't add spaces.